# What's the best way to loop through ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I'm working with Sharepoint and I have an app that creates lists in the site collection (not the app!). Creating the list isn't a problem.
I wan't to create 15 columns and add them to the default view. I prepared a "config" with the information for the list and its fields.

```
var ChangeRequestLogListConfig = {
    listName: 'ChangeRequestLog',
    fields: [
        { 'FieldTypeKind': 8, 'Title': 'STC Relevant', 'InternalName': 'STCrelevant', 'StaticName': 'STCrelevant' },
        { 'FieldTypeKind': 3, 'Title': 'Description/Reason', 'InternalName': 'DescriptionReason', 'StaticName': 'DescriptionReason' },
        { 'FieldTypeKind': 6, 'Title': 'Source of Change', 'InternalName': 'SourceOfChange', 'StaticName': 'SourceOfChange', 'Choices': { 'results': ['customer', 'internal'] } },
        //12 more objects like the above
    ]
}
```

There we come to the problem: with the rest resources `.../ViewFields/AddViewField` and `.../fields` (with http post to create new ones) only support one parameter which means I have to do 2x15 ajax calls.

What's the proper approach to doing all these 30 operations and then do a final callback? Of course I know how to loop through the array of fields, I simply have no clue how to build that final callback the proper way.

**Update / Follow-up**

With the help of a few answers I managed to build the following code:

```
var spExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getbytitle('" + listConfig.listName + "')/fields?@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'";

//map field configs to promises
var promises = listConfig.fields.map(fieldConfig => {
    return spExecutor.executeAsync({
        url: requestUrl,
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(fieldConfig),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        error: err => console.log(err)
    });
});

//Wait for all calls to be done
$.when.apply($, promises).then(callbackFn);
```

As you probably already saw, I'm not using `$.ajax` but the `SP.RequestExecutor`.
The problem: This doesn't return promises the same way as jQuery's ajax. This results in timing problems (--> 15 Calls at once, browsers mostly only support 4 parallel calls).  The code above works, if I set a breakpoint and wait 1-2 seconds between the calls it creates all fields as expected.

My follow-up question: How can I wait for the completion of the first call to init the second, then the third and so on?
I'm not sure if I'm using the promises the right way.

Comment: Can't you bundle it into fewer requests? Submitting a list of tasks for the server to complete and then respond to one big response ?

Comment: You can wrap each call in a promise, then call `Promise.all([p1, p2, ...])`. The result from the `Promise.all` will be an array, with each item being the result from each ajax call.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Nope, as said the endpoints allow only one at the time.
@NickSalloum how would I do this? `var responses = Promise.all(...)`? And what would p1,p2 be?

Comment: @Sandrooco They are also promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up doing this:

```
//Promise returning request
function executeRequest(fieldConfig, listName) {
    return function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/fields?@target='" + riskapp.utils.getSpHostUrl() + "'";
            var spExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
            spExecutor.executeAsync({
                url: requestUrl,
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(fieldConfig),
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: resolve,
                error: reject
            });
        });
    };
}

//Add fields to list according to config
function addFieldsToList(listConfig, callback) {

    //Prepare empty/resolved promise to iterate later
    var promise = Promise.resolve(null);

    //Loop through every field 
    $.each(listConfig.fields, function (i, field) {
        promise = promise.then(executeRequest(listConfig[field], listConfig.listName));
    });

    //execute callback when all fields are created
    promise.then(callback);
}
```

This executes all the calls in an order, not simultaneously.

Comment: yeah, that's another way of doing it, but they will then be strictly serialised which won't be as fast.   Having gotten `executeRequest` written, you could have still used `.map` and either `$.when` or `Promise.all()` to work on the array of Promises.   NB: `new Promise()` only works on ES6 browsers.  With jQuery you can use `$.Deferred()` instead, or use a Promise shim such as Bluebird for older browsers.

Comment: another neat way of doing serialised calls is to use `return array.reduce(function(p, field) { return p.then(...) }, Promise.resolve())`

Comment: Also, rather then passing the callback to `addFieldsToList`, you should just `return promise`, and call it like: `addFieldsToList(...).then(callback)` - separate the process from the subsequent action.

Comment: Thanks alot @Alnitak. Important in my case: The calls have to be serialized because I'm accessing the same SP list everytime whicht returns a 409 if I go simultaneously. How would you use deffereds in my solution?

Comment: If you've got standard Promises working (requiring either ES6 or a shim) then there's no need to change over to using `$.Deferred` - the ES6-style promises are superior.

Comment: That's right. Is it true that I just can put one of the polyfills in my project and it should work with IE and other ES6-incompatible browsers?

Comment: In _theory_ you can do that, yes, but I've never tried it, since I only use real browsers ;-)    Also please see my updated answer.

Comment: Tried it, works.
Me too, there are a lot of customers using IE though. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` to convert each field into a `Promise`:

```
var promises = ChangeRequestLogListConfig.fields.map(
    item => $.ajax( ... )
);
```

and then `$.when` to wait for them all to complete:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then( ... );
```

Note that this will start as many AJAX requests in parallel as your browser will permit - typically four.

**EDIT** since you've said you actually want the AJAX queries to run in series (to avoid server 409 errors) my version of your `addFieldsToList` function would look like this:

```
function addFieldsToList(listConfig) {

    return listConfig.fields.reduce(function(promise, field) {
        return promise.then(executeRequest(field, listConfig.listName));
    }, Promise.resolve(null));

}
```

avoiding passing the callback, since the return value of this function will itself be a `Promise` that you can chain:

```
addFieldsToList(myConfig).then(callback);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of $ in apply?

Comment: @Sandrooco it makes the jQuery object become the value of `this` within the `$.when` function, just as it would be if called directly with `$.when(p0, p1, ...)`

Comment: This worked superb, the only problem though: I just saw I have to use the SP.RequestExecutor to go from the appweb to the hostweb... It doesn't work because I think it doesn't support promises. How can I make "custom" promises?

Comment: this may be of use: https://technologykhabar.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/use-of-deferred-object-in-sharepoint-rest-api/

Comment: This is as far as I could get it. This article doesn't document the use of deferreds with multiple calls though.
Have a look at the updated question, might be a bit more clear.
Thanks alot!